# Simulation of a simple process code runif - R programming

Tags: r, simulation, probability

John either visits his girlfriend who lives downtown or visits his mother who lives uptown, but not both. He goes to the bus stop every evening at a random time and takes either an uptown or a downtown bus (from the same bus stop), whichever comes first. Each of the two kinds of buses arrives at the bus stop every 30 minutes with a fixed regular schedule: the arrival times for downtown buses are a or (30 + a) minutes past each hour, and that for uptown buses are b or (30 + b) minutes past each hour, where 1 ≤ a < b < 30 are two integers.

I proved that he is expected to visit his mother b-a time per month (basic probability).

I wanted to write a function `f(a,b)` which could simulate this experience once. Then I wanted to repeat the experience a large number of time to see if the actual number of time he went to see his mother gets close to b-a as we repeat the experience.

To do so, I define John's arrival time as:

```
mom <- function(a,b) {
  JAT <- runif(n=360, min=0, max=59)
  y = 0 # y would be the number of time he went to see his mother
  if(JAT > b) {
    y <- y
  } else {
    y <- y + 1
  }
  return(y)
}
```

I don't really know how to make this a proper function `f(a,b)` and my code did not even run on R (error message). Could anyone help me on how to simulate the experiment John undertake every evening? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cycle of 30 minutes that repeats, and there is one occurrence of `a` and `b` in that cycle.

Given that `a < b`, if `t` is the arrival time, the decision on which bus to take can be summarized as:

- `t <= a`: **Downtown bus**
- `a < t <= b`: **Uptown bus**
- `t > b`: **Downtown bus**

Hence, the function to calculate the number of time one of the busses is taken is:

```
bus <- function(a,b) {
  arrivals <- runif(n=360, min=0, max=30)
  downtown <- sum( arrivals<=a | arrivals>b )
  uptown   <- sum( arrivals>a & arrivals<=b )
  return(downtown) # or uptown
}
```